# Set up nginx + php to serve php files from home directories

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, freebsd, home-directory

Here is the relevant part of my nginx.conf, which does not work for php files that are located in the home directories of the users:

```
  location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
     alias /usr/home/$1/www$2;
     autoindex on;
    }

   # Serve user directories php files
    location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*\.php)$ {
        alias /usr/home/$1/www;
        try_files $2 =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /~$1$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
         include fastcgi_params;       
        }
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the log files?  What do you get instead of the php ....?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested location block to handle the `.php` files. For example.

```
location ~ ^/~(?<user>.+?)(?<path>/.*)?$ {
    alias /usr/home/$user/www$path;
    autoindex on;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

EDIT: I realised I needed to use named captures as the numeric captures go out of scope.